# Redux connect not calling mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps on initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

While debugging, I hit the following withRouter connect function but I do not hit mapStateToProps or mapDispatchToProps. I see no errors in the console but because mapStateToProps isn't getting called, I'm not seeing the values from my store show up in props.

Shouldn't the `debugger` in mapStateToProps be hit when the connect function is called since it calls mapStateToProps? My understanding is that`connect` calls the functions passed into it.

Most similar questions are trying to figure out why mapStateToProps is not being called on state change but I haven't even made it that far. I'm talking initial load of the component and the connection to the store.

I am importing withRouter and connect.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(KpiSummaryContainer) as any);

function mapStateToProps(store: any) {
  debugger;
  return {
      ...store.kpiSummaryState,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  debugger;
  return {
      selectKpiSummaryTimePeriod: (timePeriod: any) => {
                   dispatch(kpiSummaryActionCreators.onKpiSummaryTimePeriodUpdate(dispatch, timePeriod.value)); 
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you importing `withRouter` and `connect` from their respective modules?

Comment: @jmargolisvt yes I am. Apologies for not including that info

Comment: In your render are you sure you are using the Component exported from this file and not KpiSummaryContainer directly ?

Comment: @lorefnon you nailed it. Thank you so much. I was banging my head against the wall knowing it had to be something simple. I was importing KpiSummaryContainer directly and not the exported component

Comment: Oh, great. Been there, done that. Happy to be of help.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you write like below , it will work :

```
function mapStateToProps(state,ownProps) {

  return {
   Something : state.Something
  };
}
```

Then you can access to the store by this:

```
this.props.Something
```